# How do I differentiate between Longclicks and onclick events?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am trying to open one fragment when the header is clicked once and another fragment upon long click, but both of them fire at once upon click, no matter long or tapped once. How do I differentiate between the two? 
Here's my code block :

```
case R.id.market_header:
            marketHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View vi) {
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onMarketClicked(view);
                }

            });
            marketHeader.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {   
                   @Override
                   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                 TestcaseFragment2.newInstance(getFragmentManager());

                    return false;
                   }
                  }); 
            break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return true in `onLongClick` so the system knows that you have handled the event.

Comment: any clue how I can display the fragment as a popup?

Comment: yea, want the testfragment to display in an alert box /dialog box

Comment: I need the dialog to contain the contents of a fragment, sort of like a container for the fragment,so when i long click it pops up with the fragment container

Comment: So your Fragment just looks like a dialog, simply use FragmentTransaction to commit the Fragment into your container and that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should return **true** on `setOnLongClickListener`

```
marketHeader.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {   
                   @Override
                   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                 TestcaseFragment2.newInstance(getFragmentManager());

                    return true; //change here
                   }
                  });
```

**OnLongClick**  returns a `boolean` to indicate whether you have consumed the event and it should not be carried further. That is, return true to indicate that you have handled the event and it should stop here